# Optimal strategy for gambling-influenced chess

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> Alice and Bob play chess against each other. Alice wins in probability $\frac 34$ if Charlie bets on her and in probability $\frac{1}{3}$ if Charlie bets on Bob. Charlie gets a 1$ if he's right and loses one if he's wrong. Charlie would like to determine a range of bets guaranteeing him a revenue. Determine if such range exists and if it does determine the optimal bet.

So far, denoting $A=\{\text{Alice wins}\},G_A=\{\text{Charlie bets on Alice}\}$ I found that since
$$
P(A)=P(A\mid G_A)P(G_A)+P(A|G_A^c)P(G_A^c)=\frac 13+\frac{5}{12}P(G_A).
$$
Now I take great pains finding the expected value of the revenue. Am I even on the right track?

Comment: If C bets on A then C is a 3 to 1 favorite.  If C bets on B, then he is a 2 to 1 favorite.  So, the outcome of the game is affected by who C bets on, as if the person who C bets against *gets nervous*.  C can not guarantee a profit on any single game.  So, the best that C can do is always bet on A.